# Редирект на другой каталог сайта

Tags: .htaccess, apache

Как сделать редирект с `site/ynivalniki` на `site/complekty`

```
RewriteRule old-catalog /(.*) / old-catalog /$1 [R=301,L]
```

не сработало

Comment: плохо понял. но может, так вы хотите `RewriteRule ^ynivalniki/(.*)$ /complekty/$1 [R=301,L]`

Answer (score 3):

**Вариант 1**

```
redirect /ynivalniki /complekty
```

Это будет редирект со статусом `302 Fround` (временный) и без `mod_rewrite`.

**Вариант 2**

С помощью `mod_rewrite` (что в данном случае немного странно, т.к. регулярные выражения тут не нужны).

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/ynivalniki(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ynivalniki(.*)$ /complekty$1 [L,R=301]
```

В этом случаем редирект будет постоянный – `301 Moved Permanently`. Если нужно 302, думаю найдете где поменять ;)

### UPD

Оба варианта будут перенаправлять целиком разделы. То есть по ссылке `/ynivalniki/aaa?bbb=ccc` будет редирект на `/complekty/aaa?bbb=ccc`

Если вам нужно только этот один урл средиректить, то можно так:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/ynivalniki(/)?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /complekty/ [L,R=301]
```

И пожалуйста, учитесь пользоваться поиском. Здесь столько ответов на этот же вопрос.

Comment: У Вас маленькая ошибочка: `/ynivalniki2`  перенаправится на `/complekty2`, что может быть ненужным.

Comment: @kff это не ошибка, так запланировано

Answer (score 2):

Можно сделать, например, так (используется *mod_rewrite*):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^ynivalniki(\/.*)?$ /complekty$1  [L,R=301,NC]
```

В отличие от решения, предложенного @korytoff, условие записано более компактно.